# C# Code Optimization -- Finding nearest key in a SortedList

Tags: c#, .net

Just wondering if anyone can see a way to optimize this piece of code.  It is a key piece of my program and needs to run as quickly as possible. The part of the code I am unsure of is the `while` loop for finding the nearest key -- but any assistance with optimizing the code would be appreciated.

```
// TODO: Move to snippets lib or create a new collection type that supports this feature
private string _getTrait(SortedList<decimal, string> thisList, decimal thisValue)
{
    // Check to see if we need to search the list.
    if (thisList == null || thisList.Count <= 0) { return null; }
    if (thisList.Count == 1) { return thisList.Values[0]; }

    // Setup the variables needed to find the closest index
    int lower = 0;
    int upper = thisList.Count - 1;
    int index = (lower + upper) / 2;

    // Find the closest index (rounded down)
    bool searching = true;
    while (searching)
    {
        int comparisonResult = Decimal.Compare(thisValue, thisList.Keys[index]);
        if (comparisonResult == 0) { return thisList.Values[index]; }
        else if (comparisonResult < 0) { upper = index - 1; }
        else { lower = index + 1; }

        index = (lower + upper) / 2;
        if (lower > upper) { searching = false; }
    }

    // Check to see if we are under or over the max values.
    if (index >= thisList.Count - 1) { return thisList.Values[thisList.Count - 1]; }
    if (index < 0) { return thisList.Values[0]; }

    // Check to see if we should have rounded up instead
    if (thisList.Keys[index + 1] - thisValue < thisValue - (thisList.Keys[index])) { index++; }

    // Return the correct/closest string
    return thisList.Values[index];
}
```

I am using C#, .net4.0 -- I need to use a Generic SortedList ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms132319(v=vs.100).aspx )

Comment: unrelated: I'm curious to know what a method beginning with an underscore means in your codebase.

Comment: This code runs extremely fast, even for big lists. I **strongly doubt** that this is your bottleneck.

Comment: @crdx anything with an _ in my database designates it as private.  Just makes it easy to find the stuff I want when coding.

Comment: @codesparkle -- thanks for the insight, I still consider myself a novice when it comes to programming. The code looks messy to me and I felt there had to be better way to do it... Maybe I am lacking confidence rather than optimization.

Comment: Optimization starts with profiling. Don't guess where the bottlenecks are, **know** it.

Comment: There's no need for "optimization" or anything of the sort in the title.  I've already added the relevant tag for it.

Comment: Hi Anthony, your title should clearly state what your code does and there's no need to state optimisation and such in the question if it's just noise. @Jamal modified your question to better fit in line with our guidelines, but you've reverted the edits. When you post code on CR we are to review **the whole code** (and not just specific sections) on any aspect we see fit.

Comment: Languages don't need to be specified in the title of the question because we have tags that specify certain information for us and also allow search engines to see them properly. Code Review as a community has already decided that we should edit languages or other "tags" out of the title and add them to the tags list. check out this [Meta Post](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/768/18427)

Comment: I disagree -- first of all this question is over 3 years old - there is no need to edit it at this point. Second, having C# in the title makes it much easier to search on through external platforms like Google. If anyone REALLY thinks it necessary to update an old post by removing the word `Optimization` from the title feel free.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your loop is pretty well written. The only thing that sticks out to me is your use of a constant in the while loop and manually breaking.  I also prefer to use a slightly different version of CompareTo, but it doesn't make much difference:

```
while ( (lower<=upper))
{
    int comparisonResult = thisValue.CompareTo( thisList.Keys [index]);
    if (comparisonResult == 0) { return thisList.Values[index]; }

    if (comparisonResult < 0)
    {
        upper = index - 1;
    }
    else
    {
        lower = index + 1;
    } 
    index = (lower + upper) / 2; 
}
```

You might also be looking for a solution that's just easier to read or shorter. Are you familiar with LINQ? This is one possibility for how your function might look.

```
    private static string GetTraitRefactor (SortedList<decimal, string> thisList, decimal thisValue)
    {
        var keys = thisList.Keys;
        var nearest = thisValue -
            keys.Where(k => k <= thisValue)
            .Min(k => thisValue - k);
        return thisList[nearest];
    }
```

Comment: I have the constant bool in there because I need to update the index before it breaks, without the bool I think the index would miss the last update... Maybe I am wrong on that; I will try it a bit later.

Comment: Also, I know a little bit about LINQ but still learning.  That looks like something that might be worth plugging in and seeing how it runs.

Comment: Marking this as the answer as it's the only one that I got -- thanks.  While I didn't user any of the code provided you made me feel more confidant about my code and gave me some alternatives to work through.  Thanks!

Comment: Like I mentioned, your loop is well coded and straightforward enough that there's not too much to do with it.

Comment: Linq doesn't meet the "needs to run as quickly as possible" requirement.  It performs a linear search rather than binary.  The linq solution can be improved, however, by using `TakeWhile` instead of `Where`.

Answer (score 3):

The classic calculation to average indices in binary search is

```
lower + (upper - lower) / 2
```

That's because (lower + upper) / 2 can overflow.  Of course, in the 32-bit world, this is no longer very likely to happen.

The linq soution proposed in another answer does not meet your requirement of "needs to run as quickly as possible."  Linq will do a linear search rather than a binary search.

You can get rid of the `searching` variable (note that you assign it at the very end of the loop body, after all):

```
while (lower <= upper)
//...
```

I think there's also no point in adding or subtracting 1.  I once long ago did an analysis that showed that this doesn't improve the efficiency of the algorithm.  You reduce the search range by 1 on each step, but you lose that because of the division by two.  I'm not certain of this, however; it was a long time ago.

You also don't need `else` if the `if` branch returns.

Therefore:

```
while (lower <= upper)
{
    int comparisonResult = Decimal.Compare(thisValue, thisList.Keys[index]);

    if (comparisonResult == 0) { return thisList.Values[index]; }

    if (comparisonResult < 0) { upper = index; }
    else { lower = index; }

    index = lower + (upper - lower) / 2;
}
```